# Convert a Filepath string into a Filepath/Directory in Bash

Tags: bash, awk, sed, scripting

I'm trying to make a simple script that creates files from some plain/text templates.
In detail, the script parses and replaces the content of some files using `sed` and takes the filepath where the generated file should be written, from the template itself using `awk`.

Unfortunately, the filepath taken with `awk` is a string, so when I use the redirection operator "`>`" to write the `sed` output to the filepath variable, the shell gives me this error:

```
./script.sh: line 45: ~/path/to/file/generatedFile: No such file or directory
```

### Some script code

```css
// CSDdir:~/path/to/file/generatedFile

* {
    margin:                     0;
    spacing:                    0;
    border:                     0;
    text-color:                 <fg>;
    background-color:           transparent;
    border-color:               <bg>;
...
```

first lines of a template.

```sh
...

# Dirs
CUR_DIR=$( dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")" )
TEMPLATES_DIR="$CUR_DIR/templates"

...

tempDir=$( awk -F':' '$1 == "// CSDdir" { print $2; exit }' "$TEMPLATES_DIR/templateFile" )

cat "$TEMPLATES_DIR/templateFile" | sed \ # this is line 45
-e "s/<font>/$font/g" \
-e "s/<fg>/$foreground/g" \
-e "s/<bg>/$background/g" \
-e "s/<color0>/$color0/g" \
-e "s/<color8>/$color8/g" \
-e "s/<color1>/$color1/g" \
-e "s/<color9>/$color9/g" \
-e "s/<color2>/$color2/g" \
-e "s/<color10>/$color10/g" \
-e "s/<color3>/$color3/g" \
-e "s/<color11>/$color11/g" \
-e "s/<color4>/$color4/g" \
-e "s/<color12>/$color12/g" \
-e "s/<color5>/$color5/g" \
-e "s/<color13>/$color13/g" \
-e "s/<color6>/$color6/g" \
-e "s/<color14>/$color14/g" \
-e "s/<color7>/$color7/g" \
-e "s/<color15>/$color15/g" \
> $tempDir
```

*awk* takes the filepath from templateFile and put it in *tempDir*.
*sed* substitute "tags" with values and write the output in *tempDir* filepath, but it gives me the error mentioned before.

**Is there a way to convert the content of *tempDir* into a filepath / directory?

or, is there a way to do the same thing but with other methods?**

Comment: Shell doesn't have any types beyond strings. How did you set `TEMPLATES_DIR` in the first place. I suspect you used something like `TEMPLATES_DIR="~/..."`, in which case the `~` was never expanded to your home direction. `TEMPLATES_DIR=~/"..."` would be correct (assuming the quotes are needed at all).

Comment: Here is how I setted that variable  

`
# Dirs
CUR_DIR=$( dirname "$(readlink -f "$0")" )
TEMPLATES_DIR="$CUR_DIR/templates"
`

Comment: Please write before every code-snippet the filename. What's confusing: where does this come from: `~/path/to/file/generatedFile`. In the code-snippet you presented, there is nowhere `~/path/to/file/generatedFile`. In the error message there is `./script.sh: line 45:`. But since don't know which file is script.sh. Therefore we can't take a look at line 45 to see on which line the error occurred.

Comment: @AedvaldTseh you're right, i'm updating the question right now.

Comment: @chepner you centered the problem perfectly, the error was the `~`.
I found a solution by myself replacing the `~` in _tempDir_ with `$HOME` and escape character.
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @chepner, I found a solution by myself.
The problem was the `~` character that when taken by `awk`, it doesn't "expand" to home directory.

The cleaner way to solve that is to replace the `~` (if it's present) in *tempDir* with `$HOME` value and `\` character:

```sh
home=$( echo $HOME | sed 's/\//\\\//g')
tempDir=$( awk -F':' '$1 == "// CSDdir" { print $2; exit }' "$TEMPLATES_DIR/rofiConfig" | sed -e "s/~/$home/g" )
```

Now, all perfectly works.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is as chepner suggested, the ~ is not being expanded.

This is the problem:

```
// CSDdir:~/.scripts/templates/generatedFile
```

Consider writing it this way:

```
// CSDdir:/absolute-path-to-home/.scripts/templates/generatedFile
```

That said, if you want a more general solution, you'll have to tell your bash script to expand the variable.  This can be done (dangerously) with eval.  You can also perform tilde expansion using the python function `os.path.expanduser`.

Consider replacing the last line as follows:

```
>$(python -c "import os.path ; print  os.path.expanduser('$tempdir') ")
```

The line above assumes python2.

If you trust the author of the CSDir comment, you can just use an eval like this:

```
> $( eval "echo $tempdir" )
```

Comment: This is also a valid solution. Thanks!